# paginate #rows depending on screen size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

I have a Rails 3 inhouse application which is used on: 
19" touch screen, 10" iPads, 7" Tablet

I am using will_paginate / kaminari for displaying lists of data.

But how can I configure how many items per page it should display depending on the screen size?

e.g. 20 lines for a 19" display,  11 lines for a 10" display, 8 lines for a 7" display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider on the first request to your application passing via Ajax the relevant `navigator` and/or `screen` information and using that information to decide on the backend in Rails.

To get browser/OS information, see Javascript's `navigator` object and to get information about the screen dimensions, check Javascript's `screen` object.

Your Ajax controller action could store JSON versions of the navigator/screen information to `session` and a `before_filter` in `ApplicationController` could be used to set `@per_page` for use throughout your application's paginators.

```
before_filter do
  @per_page = 11 if !session[:navigator][:userAgent].match(/iPad/).nil?
  @per_page = 8  if !session[:navigator][:userAgent].match(/Android/).nil? && session[:screen][:width] < 1000
  # ...
end
```

You'd then pass `@per_page` to kaminari's pager.

Comment: Will be much easier to use rails request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] instead of javascript in this case.

Comment: Maybe, but OP also seems pretty interested in the **size** of the screen, which doesn't come reliably in HTTP headers.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. So I used a jQuery.post("/screensize", { width: screen.width, height: screen.height }); and stored it in a session variable